# Does the Filtering of angular material table will create a new copy of filtered data?

Tags: angular-material

I am having a doubt about how Angular material table works, does it creates a new copy of filtered data and assigns it to DataSource when we filter the table?

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. ium" #input>
</mat-form-field>


export class TableFilteringExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Comment: MatTableDataSource internally creates a new array with the filtered data (see https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts)

Comment: Was of much help thankyou, @uminder.